# docker-compose: (Re)Build Dockerfile from inside docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Had a hard time googling this question as most suggestions is how to do it through command line which I sadly do not have access to in this environment. Is it possible to do the equivalent of

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate
```

From inside a docker-compose file?

Comment: If you can't run that command, what can you do to run a Compose file?  Can you separately `docker-compose build`, `docker-compose push`, `docker-compose up`?

Comment: Hmm, I will double check but quite sure it's only "docker compose up -d" that is ran by the environment, I have no control over changing that

Comment: Do you have any ability to push environment variables into this system?  Or is it just a fixed `docker-compose.yml` file and absolutely nothing else?

Comment: Environment variables I can push, so if you have a workaround that way I'm all ears

Answer (score 0):

The environment you describe sounds similar to Kubernetes in a couple of ways, except that it's driven by a Docker Compose YAML file.  The strategies that work for Kubernetes will work here too.  In Compose there's no way to put "actions" in a YAML file, or flag that a service always needs to be rebuilt or recreated.  It sounds like the only thing it's possible to do in your environment is run `docker-compose up -d`.

The trick that I'd use here is to change the `image:` for a container whenever you have a change you need to deploy.  That means the image tag needs to be something unique; it could be a date stamp or source control ID.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  myapp:
    image: registry.example.com/myapp:20220209
```

Now when you have a change to your application, you (or your CI system) need to build a new copy of it, offline, and `docker push` it to a registry.  Then change this `image:` value, and push the updated file to the deployment system.  Compose will see that it's only running version 20220208 from yesterday and recreate that specific container.

If you have the ability to specify environment variables, you can use that in the Compose setup

```yaml
    image: registry.example.com/myapp:${MYAPP_TAG:-latest}
```

to avoid having to physically modify the file.